# Where is the front crash sensor location on a Fiat 500

Tags: electrical, fiat

I have a Fiat 500e 2014 that I purchased with front taken apart but with air bag sensors on their harnesses but not bolted in place. I can not find the location the two sensors should be located in the front of the vehicle. Where are the front crash sensors located on a Fiat 500e 2014?

Comment: Any bolt points close to where the wiring harness runs? That usually works as a clue. One thing is sure they win’t be fixed with duct tape...

Comment: Thank you Solar Mike. I’ll look every which way, but needs bolt hole and hole for key that sticks down, so pretty specific.  I was looking to far forward as compared to other cars.  Will go out and check now.

Comment: Thank you, found bolt hole and other hole between hood latch and headlight on back side of beam at the top.  Again thanks and Happy New Year. Jeff